# Как получить значение переменной, которая является CharField из базы данных зная id модели?

Tags: django

Моя модель:

```
class URL(models.Model):
    full_url = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    short_url = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default='')
```

Я в админке создал объект с id 1 и дал full_url и short_url определенные значения.
Теперь я хочу получить эти значения, зная номер объекта или его id.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ крайне рекомендую к прочтению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL.objects.get(id=55)` - достанет вам запись таблицы URL с id равным 55. Допустим запрос вы поместили в переменную test ( `test=URL.objects.get(id=55)` ), соответственно вы можете обращаться к полям этой записи. Если вы хотите вывести full_url у записи test - просто пишите test.full_url, т.е обращаетесь к полям через точку

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Где и как Вы должны получить?
если про orm то

```
URL.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Comment: Я не знаю, что и ответить. Я только начал изучать django. Из базы данных, наверное.

Comment: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
URL object (55)
[30/May/2021 11:04:28] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 476
 это вывод в консоль от вашей строчки кода. Мне надо значение CharField

Comment: То есть в базе данных у меня лежит объект URL с id=55, мне надо получить значение его short_url и full_url

Comment: данный код выводит Queryset объекта, вам надо вывести его в HTML страницу? или вы его собираетесь обработать на бэке?